# Cheapest solid-state way to turn a 240 VAC, 15 W resistive load on/off

Tags: switching, mosfet-driver, solid-state-relay, triac, scr

I need to be able to pulse a 240 VAC, 15 W resistive load on and back off. I need it to turn on only for a single line cycle, then it will remain off for at least 60 seconds, so perhaps the components don't necessarily need to be rated for the full 15 W since its duty cycle is so low.

Dimming and PWM aren't necessary, nor is it necessarily required that the load see the entire 240 VAC. It also doesn't matter if the supply is rectified, also it's OK if it sees only half of the waveform. Leading edge and trailing edge cutting doesn't matter, but the load should see either half a 60 Hz AC waveform or a full 60Hz AC waveform for the entire single 60 Hz line cycle period (with an extra leading and/or trailing line cycle, which would add a possible cut-in delay on the first cycle or cut-off delay on the last cycle, which is OK).

What would be the cheapest way to turn this load on and off? I really want to keep my component count to a minimum.

Comment: Welcome! How about a relay?

Comment: @winny Ouch. Yes that would work given the parameters I stated. OK, I lied. In reality I want the load turned on for only one full line cycle. If I need to turn it on for 3 line cycles to deal with cut-in and/or cutoff delay, that's ok, but really I only want it turned on for that one full line cycle. I edited my question accordingly (single cycle vs. what I originally said, 1 second).

Comment: Microcontroller to do the zero crossing detection, and a solid state relay?

Comment: @IanBland Yes I already have a microcontroller available which is already zero-cross-aware, but I think a solid state relay would be pretty expensive compared to what I'm looking for.

Comment: What exactly is the load?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It's actually, really, just a resistor. Really. But it's connected to an ADC input. The ADC input needs to be able to observe the effect of the momentarily switched-on 15W load in order to compute the supply's source impedance. That's why I want it turned on for only a single line cycle at a time, and why it can be turned off for 60 seconds or so between checks of the source impedance.

Comment: Zero crossing SSR?

Comment: @phonetagger I am curious what project requires measuring the impedance of a 240V AC source :)

Comment: @user253751 Said source also has to have a really high impedance for such a small load to produce a measurable voltage sag. Definitely not the power grid. Could be some load-shedding application downstream of a really tiny solar inverter, or something.

Answer (score 7):

A power of 15W over a cycle into a resistive load is only 68mA RMS. If your load is really just resistive you *might* be able to use a phototriac to drive the load directly. [This](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84780/appnote34.pdf) app note mentions the dv/dt commutation issue that is a non-issue when the phototriac is used conventionally to trigger a larger triac. Usually the use of such devices to directly control the load is discouraged without explanation. That would be a single 4 or 6 pin 'chip' plus a resistor for the LED (and inexpensive).

[image]

If low parts count is the primary issue, then a small triac-output or high-voltage photoMOS SSR module is the most attractive solution, but more expensive. If your load has a lot of capacitance or inductance you may have other issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to switch the load on and off at specific points on the sine waveform, a photo-MOS device might be ideal. The [TLP240](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/408/TLP240GA_datasheet_en_20200204-1102049.pdf) can handle 120 mA and 400 volts, and is in stock at Mouser for less than $2.

And [here](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/240/CPC1025N-1546516.pdf) is one that is a bit cheaper.

Comment: Using an SCR it would trigger at zero point as controlled by your microprocessor, it will turn off as soon as the voltage crosses zero. A opto isolator and a few resistors would be the circuit. Be sure the SCR holding current is below your load or it will go off as soon as the pulse does.

Comment: It might be good to apply a DC gate signal and keep it on to make sure it does not turn off too soon with a low load current. But the OP said they might want an extra leading and trailing edge.